# Ripping an audio CD via command line (whole CD as a single file)

Tags: command-line, audio, mp3, compact-disc

I have a few audiobooks that can be 15+ CDs long that I want to convert to MP3 so I don't have to keep switching CDs.  I've found an used various GUI programs out there that work, but require a bit of input for each CD.  I don't really care about tags and such.  Ideally, I would like the following:

1) Be prompted for book name (which will be the MP3 name with an incremental number at the end for CD#)

2) Enter First CD, CD auto rips and ejects

3) Enter next CD, CD auto rips and ejects (file name is the book name CD#  (IE:  BookTitle CD2).

4) Bonus points if prompting for Author and Book title, with each being a folder.

While I run and know Windows best, I'm fine with trying out Linux (Tried compiling RipIt on CentOS, but can't get it to run...  I'm a Linux newb for the most part...  Starting to learn it better though).

Comment: [EAC's command-line options](http://www.digital-inn.de/threads/eacs-command-line-options.31843/)

Comment: @techie007 While that one talks about ripping, the key thing I'm looking for is no real input needed when switching CDs (CDDB doesn't work for these as they aren't music...).

Comment: EAC doesn't seem to rip to a single MP3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good solution:  fre:ac.  [www.freac.com](http://www.freac.com)  To get the freaccmd to work at the moment though, you need to follow the steps at this link:  https://sourceforge.net/p/bonkenc/discussion/85470/thread/e8768aab/

Answer (score 0):

Well, changing the operating system just for ripping sounds a bit drastic, but I guess any reason for changing from Windows to Linux is a good one. ;)

So Assuming that you want to rip using, say, ubuntu, have a look at
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CDRipping
they also recommend several (also command line) programs to do what you want.

But I am not quite sure that I got your question in the first place. If all you want is ripping several CDs consecutively without much ado in between CDs, there a zillions of Programms, also on Windows, to do that.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/bonkenc/
http://cdexos.sourceforge.net
...
The effort to start ripping the CD is usually negligible as compared to changing the physical discs, anyway. ;)

Comment: I already have setup a VM of CentOS.  I've used several for Windows which for for ripping quiet nicely, but I get tired and annoyed with having to enter the artist/title/CD# each and every time...

Comment: I'm even fine with a batch file that runs through to do the work